# How do I disable "Verify file exists" in IIS 6 aspx Handler programmatically?

Tags: iis-6

I need to install an MVC 2 Application automatically on a series of servers. To make MVC 2 work with IIS 6 out of the box I have changed the routing to route urls with .aspx extensions as described in an article by Phil Haacked. This works fine only if the "Verify file exists" option on the aspx handler is disabled.

This prevents IIS from checking for the aspx file(which does not exist) and throwing a 404 error.

My question is how do I disable this in the handler **programmatically** in my installer?